# What kind of unit test solution for the routes in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I'm looking for the best solution to unit test the routes in an Ember.js application. I found two solutions, i would like you say to me what is the best for you.
The two implementations are availables here : http://jsbin.com/URaKULa/1/edit

```
//=====================================
// Source :
//=====================================

App = Em.Application.create({
});

App.UserEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        // here we tell the route to use its parent model 
        return this.modelFor('user');
    },
    activate: function () {
        this.controllerFor('user').set('editMode', true);
    },
    deactivate: function () {
        this.controllerFor('user').set('editMode', false);
    },
    events: {
        goBack: function () {
            this.transitionTo('user');
        }
    }
});

// defer readiness and set location's router to none in order to stop main application initialization
App.setupForTesting();

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

//=====================================
// Test :
//=====================================

//-----------------
// First solution
//-----------------
(function () {
    var originalTemplates;
    var container;
    var Router;
    var router;

    function bootTestApplication() {
        router = container.lookup('router:main');
        Ember.run(TestApp, 'advanceReadiness');
    }

    function handleURL(path) {
        return Ember.run(function () {
            return router.handleURL(path).then(function (value) {
                ok(true, 'url: `' + path + '` was handled');
                return value;
            }, function (reason) {
                ok(false, 'failed to visit:`' + path + '` reason: `' + reason);
                throw reason;
            });
        });
    }


    module('First solution for test routes', {
        setup: function () {
            Em.run(function () {

                // We create a fake test Application to isalate route
                TestApp = Em.Application.create({
                    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
                    name: "TestApp",
                    rootElement: "#qunit-fixture"
                });
                // We defer initialization and disabled location
                TestApp.setupForTesting();

                // Save the router
                Router = TestApp.Router;

                // Save a loading route just in case
                TestApp.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
                });

                // Save the global TestContainer to lookup  what you want
                container = TestApp.__container__;

                // We save the current ember templates to not impact the other unit test
                // when we will overide a few.
                originalTemplates = Ember.$.extend({}, Ember.TEMPLATES);

                // Override/mock application test for isolation
                Ember.TEMPLATES.application = Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{outlet}}");

                // You can here overide other templates if necessary
            });
        },
        teardown: function () {
            Ember.run(function () {
                // deleting the Test application
                TestApp.destroy();
                TestApp = null;
                // reset old Ember templates
                Ember.TEMPLATES = originalTemplates;
            });
        }
    });

    test('UserEditRoute', function () {
        Router.map(function () {
            this.resource('user', function () {
                this.route('edit');
            });
        });

        // Save the App.UserEditRoute to test into the isolated context
        TestApp.UserEditRoute = App.UserEditRoute;

        // we define a fake UserRoute who will return the expected model of the UserEditRoute
        var expectedUserModel = Em.Object.create({name: 'Model from user route'});
        TestApp.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend({
            model: function () {
                return expectedUserModel;
            }
        });

        // Mock of UserController and UserEditController classes
        TestApp.UserController = Em.Controller.extend({
            editMode: false
        });

        TestApp.UserEditController = Em.Controller;

        // We define an empty template
        Ember.TEMPLATES['user/edit'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile("");

        // Start TestApp application
        bootTestApplication();

        // retrieve UserController instance
        var userCtrl = container.lookup('controller:user');
        var userEditCtrl = container.lookup('controller:userEdit');

        handleURL('/user/edit');
        // assert activate hook behavior and model
        ok(userCtrl.get('editMode'));
        ok(userEditCtrl.get('content', expectedUserModel));

        // reset tested properties
        userCtrl.setProperties({
            editMode: true,
            content: null
        });

        handleURL('/');
        // assert deactivate hook behavior
        ok(!userCtrl.get('editMode'));

        // here we place other test like event handling, or to test others route's hooks
    });
})();


//-----------------
// Second solution
//-----------------
(function(){
  module('Second solution to test routes',{
    setup:function(){
    },
    teardown:function(){
    }
  });

  test('UserEditRoute',function(){
    var container = new Em.Container();
    var expectedUserModel = Em.Object.create({name: 'Model from user route'});

    container.register("controller:user", Em.Controller.extend({
      editMode: false
    }));
    container.register("route:user", Em.Route.extend({
      currentModel:expectedUserModel
    }));

    var userEditRoute = App.UserEditRoute.create({
      router : {
        container:container,
        router:{}
      },
      container:container
    });

    var userCtrl = container.lookup('controller:user');

    equal (userEditRoute.model(), expectedUserModel);
    userEditRoute.activate();
    equal (userCtrl.get('editMode'), true);
    userEditRoute.deactivate();
    equal (userCtrl.get('editMode'), false);
  });
})();
```

The first solution is based on the unit test's Ember.js team (for more details, see here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember/tests/routing/basic_test.js) The pros of this approach is you can test global behavior of the route and not test each hook. For example, if I move the "editMode" set into another hook like the "setupController", the test continue to pass and it's normal.
Moreover, with this way I can test the event handling, by add an action in the 'user/edit' template.

The big cons, of this method that is really boring, we have four times more code to test than the implementation...

The second solution is more lightweight and elegant but less flexible. We used the container class who allow a king of injection of dependances, and permit to mock all connected classes like UserRoute, or UserController. This approach ask you to mock all the necessary properties and methods used by the route internally by Emberjs (like the router for exemple).

So what's your favorite? or you have another one?