# How to unit test Routes in ember-cli app using qunit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I can't seem to get the model hooks and actions triggered from a unit test.

Any sample/blog doing this ember-cli environment would be a great help!

I found this link
[What kind of unit test solution for the routes in Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298716/what-kind-of-unit-test-solution-for-the-routes-in-ember-js?rq=1)

but route.model() is throwing errors as :transition isn't defined.

```js
import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('route:sample', 'SampleRoute', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
});

test("beforeModel hook works", function(){
    var route = this.subject();
    Ember.run(function(){
        route.set("model", "Sample data");
    })
    console.log("Model set. Was beforeModel hook called?");
});
```

The Sample Route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    beforeModel: function (transition) {
        console.log("Inside before-model hook");
    },

    afterModel: function() {
        console.log("In after-model hook");
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you add your test code here?

Comment: @PatsyIssa the model hooks aren't triggered in the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not quite how things work. `beforeModel` isn't simply called before `model` is set, and `afterModel` afterward.  They are just hooks that are called in that sequence (`beforeModel -> model -> afterModel`) as part of the lifecycle of a route.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a good way to unit tests Routes.  If you have specific `beforeModel` logic that you need to test, then maybe you can just call `beforeModel` directly?  I have found that Route logic is best tested through acceptance-style tests, since you then have the Route being invoked in the same way it will be when the application is actually running.